# How to restrict the user input to five digits?

Tags: c#, validation

I'm trying to restrict the user to only input 5 digits into the console for C#. I have my code error check the user, but for some reason after I type let's say...6 digits, the console stops after the while loop initiates. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong please? Thank you in advance!

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the the zip code of the contact.");
temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (Console.ReadLine().Length != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
    temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (Console.ReadLine().Length == 5)
    {
        temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        address.zipCode = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you can't type anything into the console when it hits the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes, I cannot type anything when the while loop hits. I also tried adding the break statement at the end of my if statement but it's still stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing console multiple times. Check for length of your captured input - `temp`. Try this:

```
var temp = Console.ReadLine();
while (temp.Length > 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
    temp = Console.ReadLine(); 
}

address.zipCode = int.Parse(temp);
```

Comment: For some reason, the code is asking me to input the 5 digits twice?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to delete some code. This works! Thank you sooo much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use like this also.. if u want to check all the lengths.

```
if (Console.ReadLine().Length == 5)
    {
        temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        address.zipCode = temp;
    }
else{
while (Console.ReadLine().Length != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
    temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way...

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the the zip code of the contact.");
            var temp = Console.ReadLine();
            string zipcode = string.Empty;
            while (temp.Length != 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
                if (temp.Length == 5)
                {
                    zipcode = temp;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.Write(zipcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use Console.Readline() again and again

change your code like this.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the the zip code of the contact.");
     var temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (temp.ToString().Length != 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
            temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (temp.ToString().Length == 5)
            {
                temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
        }
```

(to save from null reference you can do if(temp < 100000 && temp > 9999) also.)

Comment: Console.Readline() tries to read a value which is already with you hence you dont need to do Read agains, that is the reason you were getting a delay. The above code is tested and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your statements as

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the the zip code of the contact.");

do
{
    temp = Console.ReadLine();
    if (temp.Length!=5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
    }
    else
    {
        address.zipCode = temp;
    }
} while(temp.Length!=5);
```

done!

Answer (score 0):

Please view the code given below. I think this will fulfill your requirement. I have found that you have use **address.zipCode** which has not been declared anywhere in given code so I have replace the **address.zipCode** with **zipCode**.

```
        int temp,zipCode;

        bool breakLoop = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the the zip code of the contact.");

        while (breakLoop == false)
        {
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userInput.Length != 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error. Zip code is not 5 digits. Please enter a valid number.");
                continue;
            }

            int.TryParse(userInput, out temp);
            if (temp == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error. Please enter a valid number.");
                continue;
            }                

            zipCode = temp;
            breakLoop = true;
            break;

        }
```

Please let me know if you have any problem with the code.